# Query json using filter with array as value

Tags: arrays, json, loops, filter

I have the following json data with `videos` array, where several declarations are set inside. As can be seen, there is a parameter `category` and `team` valued with another array with names of the participants.

```
{
    "videos" : [
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5678",
            "category" : "Enterview",
            "team" : ["Prince Kyle","Rod Patrón"]
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Rod Patrón","Tony Backy","Prince Kyle"]
        },
        {
            "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0186",
            "category" : "Post-Game",
            "team" : ["Risto Stoichkov"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to loop according to a combination of category and team (which contain more than one value).

I tried this code below, where I want to query only Post-Game videos with Risto and Tony:

```
var filterList = data.videos
   .filter(({ category }) => category === "Post-Game")
   .filter(({ team }) => team === ["Risto Stoichkov", "Tony Backy"])
```

It works for category, however, I can't loop the names. As can be seen, my intention is to apply more than one name if necessary.

Comment: I proposed the modified scripts for achieving your goal by supposing that you want to achieve your goal using Javascript. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to filter the value in your question.
- You want to use the values of `category` and `team` as the filter values.
- You want to achieve this using Javascript.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at `.filter(({ team }) => team === ["Risto Stoichkov", "Tony Backy"])`, `team` is an array. So, in this case, the arrays are compared. It is required to modify this.

#### Pattern 1:

When your script is modified it becomes as follows.

```js
const data = {
  "videos": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5678",
      "category": "Enterview",
      "team": ["Prince Kyle", "Rod Patrón"]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234",
      "category": "Post-Game",
      "team": ["Rod Patrón", "Tony Backy", "Prince Kyle"]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0186",
      "category": "Post-Game",
      "team": ["Risto Stoichkov"]
    }
  ]
};
var filterList = data.videos
  .filter(({ category }) => category === "Post-Game")
  .filter(({ team }) => ["Risto Stoichkov", "Tony Backy"].some(e => team.includes(e)));
console.log(filterList)
```

#### Pattern 2:

I thought that in this case, your goal might be achieved using one `filter`. The sample script is as follows.

```js
const data = {
  "videos": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5678",
      "category": "Enterview",
      "team": ["Prince Kyle", "Rod Patrón"]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234",
      "category": "Post-Game",
      "team": ["Rod Patrón", "Tony Backy", "Prince Kyle"]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0186",
      "category": "Post-Game",
      "team": ["Risto Stoichkov"]
    }
  ]
};
var filterList = data.videos
  .filter(({ category, team }) => category === "Post-Game" && ["Risto Stoichkov", "Tony Backy"].some(e => team.includes(e)));
console.log(filterList)
```

#### Pattern 3:

I thought that when an object is prepared for searching values, the process cost might be able to be reduced. The sample script is as follows.

```js
const data = {
  "videos": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5678",
      "category": "Enterview",
      "team": ["Prince Kyle", "Rod Patrón"]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234",
      "category": "Post-Game",
      "team": ["Rod Patrón", "Tony Backy", "Prince Kyle"]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0186",
      "category": "Post-Game",
      "team": ["Risto Stoichkov"]
    }
  ]
};
var names = ["Risto Stoichkov", "Tony Backy"];
var obj = names.reduce((o, e) => ({...o, [e]: true}), {});
var filterList = data.videos
  .filter(({ category, team }) => category === "Post-Game" && team.some(e => obj[e]));
console.log(filterList)
```

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)